# Can I tell if the iPhone has a passcode?

Tags: iphone, security, locking

I'm developing an application that asks for a PIN when you start it. That's not great, but I can live with it. The problem is I'm being asked to ask for the PIN each time the phone wakes from sleep, too. Combined with the OS asking for its passcode, it's too much.

Is there any legitimate way to detect if the phone has a passcode required for waking, so I can skip requiring a PIN in this case? I don't want to know the PIN and I don't actually care if it was locked (for instance, if the phone was asleep very briefly), I just want to know that the data is in some way "protected."

Comment: I am having the same requirement.. could you be able to help me out with how you solved the problem?

Comment: I never found an answer. I settled on requiring a password even if the device was protected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For AppStore or not? If the former, no way.

---

In 3.x, the passcode is stored on the keychain, that means you have to get into the SpringBoard process to determine whether a passcode exists and nonempty. If you are in SpringBoard, calling `-[SBAwayController isPasswordProtected]` will determine if the device has passcode.

Comment: could you tell me how I can get into SpringBoard process because I want to use this same functionality in my code...

Comment: Kenny, your huge amount of rep is well deserved!

Answer (score 0):

I created a [very ugly workaround](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/12/01/enforcing-ios-security-settings-in-third-party-applications/) for this same issue.

Comment: This workaround is designed for apps that are not installed through the App Store, so the answer is probably no.