# getting into SpringBoard process in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ipad, password-protection

I was having a requirement in my app where I need to check whether the iphone/ipad has a passcode protect set and If not, my app needs to notify the user to set a passcode protect for the device... I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547295/can-i-tell-if-the-iphone-has-a-passcode) where a user says that if I can get to the springboard process and use the `[SBAwayController isPasswordProtected]` functionality, I can know if the passcode is set or not..

My problem is I do not know how to get to the springboard process and I dont know how to use the above code to work.

It would be great if someone could help me out in this.

Comment: Are you trying this for jailbroken phones or for App Store?

Comment: neither.. my app would be an enterprise app and hence I need this additional security option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a non-jailbroken iPhone, there's no way to access the Springboard process and no *direct* way to determine whether the user has set a passcode. You can sort-of detect passcode locking by [creating a protected file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4) and then waiting to see whether you get locked out of it, but I don't think you can ever definitively say that the user has *not* set a passcode using this approach.

In an enterprise environment, you can require passcodes by setting policies at the device level, using the instructions in Apple's [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf), which may be a better solution.

See also [How can I find out if the iPhone user currently has a passcode set and encryption enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806455/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-iphone-user-currently-has-a-passcode-set-and-encryption).